# A tag question with third conditional

Tags: tag-questions

> If he had joined the meeting, he could have learned many things, ______?

I am hesitating between two probable answers —
'couldn't he have' and 'couldn't he'.

Which one is correct or what else might be the correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

*Couldn't he* is correct:

> If he had joined the meeting, he could have learned many things, *couldn't he*?

Alternate wording:

> If he had joined the meeting, he could have learned many things, *could he not*?

There are also the more informal alternatives

> If he had joined the meeting, he could have learned many things, *right*?
>   If he had joined the meeting, he could have learned many things, *yes*?

Comment: Used in speech, I think "...right?" is best in most cases. Also it avoids being repetitive and is easier to speak.